# Windows SQL Database row order?

Tags: sql, database, windows, sql-server-2012

As my question states:

Is it possible to make Windows SQL show the rows in certain order when I right click a DB table and select edit all rows?

Comment: what do you mean about Windows SQL

Comment: @marc_s Actually there is a Windows SQL - Windows Internal Database, can be installed as a component and is a specialized express edition.

Comment: Maybe http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: That will show the order I specify only when I use a query, I'm trying to get a certain order when I right click on a table from a DB and use the edit all rows option.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what exactly you mean with "Windows SQL". It's the first time I heard that term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a default for this, but what you can do is select the edit command on your table as normal, then right click on the results pane (outside the data area as shown below) and select Pane -> SQL:

[image: Where to click]

You can then see the command used to select your data in a separate pane and can add your own order by clause to that, once you've done that, hit execute SQL and you will have an editable grid sorted by whatever you typed in:

[image]